# How to split pandas frames to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a code where I am finding the correlation within columns of my data and printing the result as a data frame

```
correlation= Answer0.corr()

corr_self=(correlation.where(numpy.triu(numpy.ones(correlation.shape),k=3).astype(numpy.bool)).stack()
        .sort_values(ascending=False))
frame_5=corr_self.to_frame()
```

[image: Returns something like this]

How can I seperate that frame into three diff columns?

Answer (score 0):

Considering column name is "scenario" and column values are space separated :

Frame_5.scenario.str.split(expand=True)

Let me know how it works, otherwise I will give elaborated solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Your solution also works.